# Identify Hidden Form Value Without an ID or Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, greasemonkey

I am writing a Greasemonkey script and I need to be able to take the value from a hidden form element and set it to a variable.

The hidden form value looks like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ASIN" value="B009MO89Y4" />
```

I have no ID, class, or any way I can see to set the "value" to a variable. This needs to work dynamically and I currently have no way to establish a class or ID to this value.

Is there a Javascript (or jQuery) method to set this?

In other words:

Find "input" with name "ASIN" and set .val() to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector and assignment:

```
$("input[name='ASIN']").val(); <---- returns value of that input

var inputVal = $("input[name='ASIN']").val(); <-- Assigns it

var temp = "Stuff";
$("input[name='ASIN']").val(temp); <----Assigns the value of the temp var.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I kept trying something simpler that just wasn't working correctly. Some of the pages had an ID of #ASIN with the value already set so I just set it up as #ASIN. Never imagined it'd be that easy :)
Yet again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can select it via. name in **jQuery** like so:

```
var bar = "Example"; // Example text, to be used in val().
var x = $('input[name="ASIN"]').val(bar);  
// Sets the variable x to be the value bar for the input with the name ASIN.
```

Here's a working jQuery **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eascR/1/).**

---

In pure **Javascript ***:

```
var bar = "Example";  
document.getElementsByName("ASIN")[0].value = bar;
```

Here's a working Javascript [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eascR/).

---

**Please note that although `document.getElementsByName` is supported well in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, it has [limited browser support.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125) in IE and Opera.*

Comment: Note that `document.getElementsByName` has limited browser support: [W3C DOM Compatibility - Core](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125)

Comment: @cmptrgeekken I've Incorporated that into the answer, thanks. Just thought it would be nice to chuck in a pure Javascript way as opposed to just jQuery answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input[name="ASIN"]').val(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 $('input[name="ASIN"]').val();
```

Var:

```
var hiddenAsin = $('input[name="ASIN"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your selection with any attribute.

```
$('input[name=ASIN]').val("New Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector that targets inputs of type hidden. It should look like that:

```
$('input[type=hidden]');
```

or simpler:

```
$(':hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

For pure javascript:

Try `document.getElementsByName('name')`.
Note that cmptrgeekken pointed out that this has [limited browser-support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125) (although that would not be an issue with greasemonkey in FF).

As an alternative, if that hidden element has a fixed place you could also access it by index-number in a predictable collection that you got from `knownParent.getElementsByTagName('tag')[#]`  (So the first hidden inputtag inside a form would be number 0).

Another variation is to get (again) `knownParent.getElementsByTagName('tag')` and loop over that collection to see what element has the 'name' attribute set that you seek.
Simply do:

```
var target=knownParent.getElementsByTagName('input'), L=target.length;
           while(L--){ if(target[L].name==='name'){target=target[L]; break;} }
alert(target.value); //target is now the element you seek.
```

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AX47e/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0...)
{
    //go through each input and look for the name "ANSI" and the type is hidden.

     //and do your changes. 
}
```

this is for javascript remember.

with this you should be able to get that specific hidden form without an ID nor a Class assigned to that specific form.

Comment: `for(int i = 0...)` ? There is no int data type in Javascript as far as I know. You probably mean `for(var i=0; ...)`

Comment: ahh yes indeed, my bad, its the habbit haha. but yeah you catched my drift. with this it should help him solve his issue.